# How use SQL to SUM across all related rows where one row contains a matching keyword

Tags: sql

I'm working with survey data where each survey has 1 or 2 rows of data, each row has a score, and row 1 has keywords. I need to SUM all the survey scores where row 1 contains a certain keyword.

I'm trying to find a non-interative way to SUM the Score across multiple rows for each unique survey that contains a certain keyword

```
   SURVEYGUID   ANSWER_NUMBER     SCORE  KEYWORDS
      FOO            1             3     MILK EGGS JUICE
      FOO            2            10  
      WIZ            1             1     TOAST
      WIZ            2             5
      BAR            1             5     MILK TOAST
      BAR            2             2
```

IN pseudo code, it's easy:

```
CALC_SCORE (txt) =
   Find all SURVEYGUIDs where Keywords contains 'txt'
   Then SUM all Scores for that list of SURVEYGUIDS
```

CALC_SCORE (MILK) would find surveys FOO and BAR, then SUM (3+10) + (5+2)

CALC_SCORE (TOAST) would find WIZ and BAR, then SUM (1+5) + (5+2)

Is there some kind of join or pivot that allows me to do that in a single, or maybe two SQL queries?

(My project is Rails/Activerecord fwiw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Score) FROM MyTable WHERE SurveyGUID IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT SurveyGUID FROM MyTable WHERE Keywords LIKE '%MILK%')
```

**EDIT:** If you're concerned about getting false positives (due to words like "MILKSHAKE" or "BUTTERMILK"), you could use the following technique:

```
SELECT SUM(Score) FROM MyTable WHERE SurveyGUID IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT SurveyGUID FROM MyTable WHERE 
    Keywords = 'MILK' OR 
    Keywords LIKE 'MILK %' OR 
    Keywords LIKE '% MILK' OR 
    Keywords LIKE '% MILK %')
```

Comment: thank you! am trying to convert that to activerecord right now to test it!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(m.score)
FROM MyTable m 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT surveyguid 
   FROM MyTable WHERE keywords LIKE '%MILK%') g ON g.surveyguid = m.surveyguid

SELECT SUM(m.score)
FROM MyTable m 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT surveyguid 
   FROM MyTable WHERE keywords LIKE '%TOAST%') g ON g.surveyguid = m.surveyguid
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as only row 1 has the keywords this should work. Otherwise you'll need one of the other answers that uses a subquery with distinct.

```
SELECT SUM(t.SCORE)
FROM myScoreTable AS t
  INNER JOIN myScoreTable AS mt
    ON t.SURVEYGUID = mt.SURVEYGUID
WHERE mt.KEYWORDS LIKE '%MILK%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can use a subquery or a self-JOIN to do that.

But that masks a serious problem in your database design: by storing what is essentially an array of keywords in a single field, you are violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore the 1st normal form.

Your approach also brings some practical problems, for example:

- `LIKE '%MILK%'` will find "MILKSHAKE" as well, not just "MILK".
- Indexing is harder - "normal" indexes do not help with suffix-search such as `LIKE '%MILK%'` and full-text index may not be available or practical on your DBMS.

And what is this funny business of "first row having keywords" and second being without them? I think you are setting yourself up for bigger problems down the road unless you normalize your model...

Comment: I've edited my response (the accepted answer) to compensate for the false-positive problem (i.e. getting hits for "MILKSHAKE"). It makes the query uglier and probably a bit slower, but it's doable. In theory I also agree that the data model is pretty busted--hopefully when they do next year's surveys, they clean it up!--but if the OP's job is to extract data from the surveys they've already received, that's water under the bridge. Having had to deal with ridiculous data models in legacy code that can't change, I can sympathize :)